# Android Upload Image from camera and gallery using Retrofit

Tags: android, file-upload, android-camera, retrofit, android-gallery

I am using Retrofit to upload images to server but I am unable to complete and i can't even find what's the error in the code.

I don't need to show result of image to user before uploading but only need to get the file to upload when the user hits the signup button.

This is used to Capture Images:

```
fun dispatchTakePicture(){
    var takePictureIntent:Intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    //Ensure for atleast one camera activity
    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null){
        var photoFile: File? = null
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
            toast("dispatchTakePicture"+photoFile.toString())
        }catch (e:IOException){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,e.printStackTrace().toString())
        }

        if(photoFile !=null) {
            var photoUri:Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.android.fileprovider",photoFile)
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoUri)
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        }
    }
}
```

This code is for getting image from gallery:

```
 private fun getImageFromGallery(){
    val intent:Intent = Intent()
    intent.setType("image/*")
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE)
}
```

Here is where I handle the result:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    var bitmap:Bitmap

    Log.i("OnActivityResult","Before checking data Null")

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.data!=null){
        Log.i("OnActivityResult","After checking data Null")

        bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        toast("OnActivityResult"+bitmap.toString())
        Log.i("OnActivityResult","END of function checking data Null")
    }
    else if(requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {
        Log.e("onActivityResult()->","Gallery Result")
        var targetUri:Uri = data!!.data
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(contentResolver.openInputStream(targetUri))
            toast("OnActivityResult"+bitmap.toString())
            Log.e("onActivityResult()->",bitmap.toString())
            global_photoFile = File(targetUri.toString())
            Log.e("onActivityResult()->",global_photoFile.toString())
            Log.e("onActivityResult()->",currentPhotoPath.toString())
        }catch (e:FileNotFoundException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }



}
```

Retrofit CallBack:

```
        val call:Call<ResponseBody> = userClient.performRegistration(username,email,password, location,requestFile)

        call.enqueue(object :Callback<ResponseBody>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG+"-> onFailure",t?.printStackTrace().toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
                try {
                    if (response?.code() == 201) {
                        Log.d("onResponse->","User Created")
                        toast(response.code().toString())
                        //showLogin()
                    }
                    else{
                        toast("Some other Response")
                        toast(response?.code().toString())
                    }
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,e.printStackTrace().toString())
                }
            }

        })
```

Retrofit Request Method:

```
@Multipart
@POST("profile/")
Call<ResponseBody> performRegistration(@Part("username") RequestBody username,
                                       @Part("email")    RequestBody email,
                                       @Part("password") RequestBody password,
                                       @Part("location") RequestBody location,
                                       @Part MultipartBody.Part profile_pic);
```

This is my sign-up method:

```
fun performSignup(){

    val name_et:String = et_full_name.text.toString()
    val email_et:String = et_email_address.text.toString()
    val password_et:String = password.text.toString()
    val location_et:String = location.text.toString()


    var username:RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,name_et)
    var email:RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,email_et)
    var password:RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,password_et)
    var location:RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM,location_et)

    val mainfile:File = File(currentPhotoPath)
    var filePart:RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse(contentResolver.getType(Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath.toString()))),
            mainfile)

    var requestFile:MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_pic",mainfile.name,filePart)//....}
```

This is the error line:

```
  MediaType.parse(contentResolver.getType(
  Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath.toString()))),
            mainfile)

    var requestFile:MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_pic",mainfile.name,filePart)
```

LogCat:

```
  --------- beginning of crash
    2018-08-26 15:50:32.458 31602-31602/com.example.viredapp 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.viredapp, PID: 31602
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int 
java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:1059)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:187)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1010)
    at okhttp3.MediaType.get(MediaType.java:53)
    at okhttp3.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:106)
    at com.example.viredapp.ui.SignUpActivity.performSignup(SignUpActivity.kt:87)
    at com.example.viredapp.ui.SignUpActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(SignUpActivity.kt:67)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: In retrofit callback, which method has been called onFailure or onResponse?

Comment: I need to send the user data to server, So I check the response in the call back , If it's 201 ,The user is created. I am stuck at this point. So i did not implement the rest of what to call in onResponse and onFailure

Comment: Try debug your code. Check request parameter and callback of the request .

Comment: I did so but the control never reaches there. As soon as I select image from gallery the app reopens again .

Comment: @AbuYousuf I got the error while Using FIle in creating MultipPart.Body parameter ,I while update the question ,Can you figure out what's it!!! The error is ** Null Pointer Exception: Attemp to invoke virtual method CharSequenece.length()**

Comment: Post your code corresponding to that error

Comment: var filePart:RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            `MediaType.parse(contentResolver.getType(Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath.toString()))),
            mainfile) `
** This is the line gives me error **

Comment: Edit your question and post that code in question and also add error log

Comment: @AbuYousuf Is it clear now?

Comment: Check `currentPhotoPath` is null or not before parsing it